# DataTables left border not displayed on mobile devices

Tags: css, datatable, datatables

The left border of the cells in the first column (including the header) is displayed on desktop as it should but disappears on mobile devices: https://medien.lb.madsack.de/rnd/jchrist/autotabelle.html

[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OjbB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your Rang column actually disappears on mobile devices because it cannot fit. That's due to the table being too wide / having too many columns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I gave priorities to the columns and "Rang" was meant to disappear at first on mobile devices. My workaround now is to keep the first column "Rang". But my intention originally was to hide it and nevertheless have a left border for the cells in the first of the kept columns.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: Your table is not responsive.

You don't see the border, because some of the table is cut off. Your "Rang" column is not displayed.